# Peek() and remove() methods for Queue implementation in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, queue

I want to implement peek and remove methods , similar to Java's Queue.peek() and Queue.remove() , in Blackberry application. I have a custom queue implementation, but how do I get to peek at elements and remove elements from queue?

Please help,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [Arrays](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/Arrays.html) class... if you need to peek, take last element from Object array, to remove just delete last one:

```
class Queue {
    private Object[] mElements = new Object[] {};

    public void enqueue(Object element) {
        Arrays.insertAt(mElements, element, 0);
    }

    public Object dequeue() {
        Object result = null;
        if (null != mElements && 0 < mElements.length) {
            result = mElements[mElements.length - 1];
            Arrays.remove(mElements, result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Object peek() {
        if (null != mElements && 0 < mElements.length)
            return mElements[mElements.length - 1];
        else
            return null;
    }

    public void remove() {
        if (null != mElements && 0 < mElements.length)
            Arrays.remove(mElements, peek());
    }
}
```

Using example:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {
    public Scr() {
        Queue queue = new Queue();
        queue.enqueue(new String("3"));         
        queue.enqueue(new Boolean(true));
        queue.enqueue(new Integer(1));      
        //see "3" in console
        System.out.println(queue.peek());
        //see "3" still there
        System.out.println(queue.peek());
        //remove "3"
        queue.remove();
        //see "true" in console
        System.out.println(queue.peek());       
        //dequeue all elements
        Object element = null;
        while ((element = queue.dequeue()) != null) {
            System.out.println(element.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.remove` is not documented since OS 4.0 and for good reason: it doesn't work in some versions.

Comment: @MisterSmith, thank you for comment, can you give some references for this information? Thank you again!

Comment: This is the javadoc for 4.2.1, where you can see that the methods are not listed: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/net/rim/device/api/util/Arrays.html

Comment: Note that `arrays.add` is not listed either, but unlike `remove`, it does the job.

Comment: @MisterSmith thank you for answer, actually my question was about this part of your comment "it doesn't work in some versions" - can you give a reference for this information or some test case to dublicate an issue? It would be very useful, thank you!

Comment: In my case, I saw incorrect behavior when calling `remove` on a nested `Persistable` holder object. Can´t post the code because it is too large. Tested with plain Integers with no persistence and seems to work.

Comment: @MisterSmith if you wish, you could post about this Array.remove issue (including a large sample code) in a separate question and drop a link here, since it could be a pitfall for many of us! Thank you for quick answers!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use a [Vector](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/java/util/Vector.html) to do these types of operations - `firstElement()` to peek at the first in the list, `lastElement()` to peek at the last, or `elementAt()` to look at anything in between.  Then use `removeElementAt()` to remove an element.